# How should I search up parts for basic hard-wired computer? (really basic, no, more basic than that)

Tags: transistors, analog

I'm looking to build a computer the size that I can use small **jumper cables for the programming, no soldering**. Of course it won't be able to do much more than binary counting, etc.

What kind of parts would I use? I would like to **assemble inverters and diodes to build the AND gates, XOR gates, etc**. on my own. I would however need a way to ensure consistent **timing**, so I would need a CPU clock, and it would need to be **slow enough for debugging** purposes.

For those of you who have built computers inside the Minecraft game, that is what I have in mind, except I want it in the real world.

Can you point me to the right class of parts that I should be using? I would like to keep everything on the surface, so I don't want to buy pre-built XOR gates, for example, I would like to keep it to diodes and inverters and then whatever timing mechanism I would be needing.

Actually I was tempted to use magnetic relay switches for the AND gates, cause it makes that cool clicking sound and has an inherent delay.

Can you outline what I need to build such a computer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Harvard_Mark_I_Computer_-_Left_Segment.jpg

Comment: With your "No soldering" requirement, you're not going to get much. Even relay-based computers would require soldering.

Comment: You could use tinkertoys: http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~cfs/472_html/Intro/TinkertoyComputer/TinkerToy.html

Comment: Could use solderless breadboards, but would be a lot of work. For something as small as a counter I could see it working with NFET/PFET cmos on a solderless board.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a computer. If you are thinking "a computer that can calculate the sum of two single-digit binary numbers (1 or 0)" then you could probably do it on a breadboard.  I'd start there.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a lot of space.

http://www.homebrewcpu.com/ is an example of someone who's done this with wirewrap and TTL logic, not individual transistors. If you're serious about doing this, and don't want to solder, wirewrap is a good option. Another example: http://www.nzeldes.com/HOC/Handwired.htm . Wirewrap is easier to undo than solder, has less risk of damage to parts. It takes up more space and isn't good with high speed signals, which is why it's fallen out of use.

As for components, you'll need transistors. The NMOS 6502 CPU has about 3,500 of them. If you buy through-hole 2n3904 on digikey that will cost you about £60 and a lifetime of assembling them.

The relay option could lead you to duplicate the Zuse Z4: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z4_(computer) (attractive wooden cabinetry and 4kw power supply not included).

Clocking is the least of your worries; you could start with a pushbutton actuated by a cam on a cranking handle, giving you a variable rate of a few Hz.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to build a computer using discrete transistors?

Like:

http://hackaday.com/2011/02/28/2-bit-full-adder-using-just-thirty-six-555-timers/

http://hackaday.com/2012/04/20/building-a-computer-with-discrete-transistors/

http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/4-Bit_Computer

http://hackaday.com/2010/01/11/194-transistor-clock-will-blow-your-mind/

http://hackaday.com/2009/10/30/processor-built-with-transistor-transistor-logic/

Not all of these are pure transistors, but they use ttl chips, which you can easily build using discrete parts. If you are into killing time with mindless tedious repetition. Have fun.

Comment: The clock is actually quite aesthetically pleasing, and the 4-bit computer looks like it's in reach of the averagely determined sane hobbyist.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your requirement that there can be no soldering, you might want to look at the [Duo Adept](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2011/06/20/duo-adept-an-8-bit-homebrew-computer/), which was constructed using 100 mostly TTL chips and 17 solderless breadboards.  Note all the wires!  One would not want to get a tool or hand underneath a bunch of those and accidentally pull some out.

Obviously you could make a less capable computer using the same type of breadboards and a lot of transistors.

You could use these [male-to-male jumpers](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10897) for programming.